# How to minimized repet coding in Select Case

Tags: vb.net

I Want to know how to write common coding for Select Case.

```
Select Case cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1)
            Case Is = "02"
                Dim crReport As New crReportPage
                With crReport
                    .SetDatabaseLogon(strUser, strPass)
                    .SetParameterValue("@Parameter", cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
                    .SetParameterValue("@SortingOrder", cboSortingOrder.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
                End With
            Case Is = "03"
                Dim crReport As New crReportRateCategory
                With crReport
                    .SetDatabaseLogon(strUser, strPass)
                    .SetParameterValue("@Parameter", cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
                    .SetParameterValue("@SortingOrder", cboSortingOrder.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
                End With
            Case Is = "04"
                Dim crReport As New crReportRateSubCategory
                With crReport
                    .SetDatabaseLogon(strUser, strPass)
                    .SetParameterValue("@Parameter", cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
                    .SetParameterValue("@SortingOrder", cboSortingOrder.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
                End With
            Case Is = "05", "06", "07"
                Dim crReport As New crReportMaterialColourBox
                With crReport
                    .SetDatabaseLogon(strUser, strPass)
                    .SetParameterValue("@Parameter", cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
                    .SetParameterValue("@SortingOrder", cboSortingOrder.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
                End With
            Case Is = "08"
                Dim crReport As New crReportPosition
                With crReport
                    .SetDatabaseLogon(strUser, strPass)
                    .SetParameterValue("@Parameter", cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
                    .SetParameterValue("@SortingOrder", cboSortingOrder.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
                End With
        End Select
```

In above cording there are common (repeating) cording. I want to know how to put all in one section.

Comment: The way to avoid repeating the same code is almost always to declare a method and put the otherwise-repeated code into it, then call that method multiple times. In this case, that relies on the `crReportPage`, `crReportRateCategory`, etc, all inheriting the same base class or implementing the same interface that `SetDatabaseLogon`, etc, are all members of. That means that you can declare a parameter of that common type and then pass each different object as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

For all these things to even have the same properties/methods they must surely descend from a common parent object, or implement a common interface (and if they don't, they should) meaning you can:

```
    Dim crReport As ParentTypeOrInterface
    
    Select Case cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1)
        Case "02"
            crReport = New crReportPage
            
        Case "03"
            crReport = New crReportRateCategory
            
        Case "04"
            ...
     End Select

     With crReport
         .SetDatabaseLogon(strUser, strPass)
         .SetParameterValue("@Parameter", cboReportType.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 2))
         .SetParameterValue("@SortingOrder", cboSortingOrder.SelectedValue.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
     End With
```